# Catalogue search index not re indexing

Tags: reindex

I just updated form magento 1.7 to 1.9 and everything on my front end is working perfect. The only problem i have encountered is when i came to re-indexing my catalogue search index and a extension called "Lucene Search Index" it isnt timing out all it is saying is that 
"There was a problem with reindexing process." also it is unsuccessfully with the SSH reindexing.

Please help if you can, Thank you

**If you need me to put up the errors form the SSH just comment and ask as it is very long so didnt want the post to be to overwhelming **

Comment: have you checked your logfiles?

Comment: no i havent but this exception comes up when i run the SSH 

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that cosponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (main.parent_id = '8473') AND (ciss.stock_status = 1)' at line 2' in /home/senorepublic_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

also if i need to check my log files how would i do tha? (im new new to magento)

Comment: you can find your logfiles in magentoroot/var/log

Comment: in the log file it gives me these exception :

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access 
violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (maim.parent_id = '8473') 
AND (ciss.stock_status = 1)' at line 2' in /home/senorehe/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Comment: Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
use near 'WHERE (main.parent_id = '8473') AND (ciss.stock_status = 1)' at line 2' 
in /home/senorehe/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234

Comment: we're having similar problems, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830989/magento-reindexall-fails-with-same-sql-syntax-error-on-2-indexes ... it seems Magento is producing a malformed query. Perhaps something to do with the Lucene search plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During indexing, this type of problem is usually seen when an integrity constraint fails in some tables of database. You can see the exact error in your case in var/log/exception.log file.

P.S. If it is an integrity constraint failure. try truncating the table in which the failure occurs (will be listed in the log file) and try again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what it says in my exception log 

2014-06-02T13:59:53+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (main.parent_id = '8473') AND (ciss.stock_status = 1)' at line 2

Then it runs Trace #0 - #21 but nothing says failed , fail or error so how do i know where the error is?